Iniciar sesión con facebook con @capacitor-community/facebook-login
Estoy utilizando el plugin @capacitor-community/facebook-login para iniciar sesión con facebook, pero funciona en algunas cuentas y en otras no, en las que no puedo ingresar, la ventana emergente que muestra dice lo siguiente:
Función no disponible
En este momento, el inicio de sesión con Facebook no está disponible debido a que estamos actualizando otros detalles de la app. Vuelve a intentarlo más tarde.
Estoy siguiendo paso a paso la documentación del plugin.
